# Android NDK Samples cannot find header files

Tags: android, eclipse, android-ndk

I am trying to look at the source code for the OpenARToolkit Android SDK, which uses the Android NDK. It currently only works with the old Eclipse IDE, and it is been a massive pain to get working. I'm using Ubuntu 5.10, with all the latest SDK and NDK files, on the latest version on Eclipse, and JDK 1.8.0_66.

This is what my PATH variable looks like:

```
    seth@seth-P65-P67SE:~/android-ndk-r10e$ echo $PATH
    /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/home/seth/android-ndk-r10e
```

I'm trying to run the sample NDK app HelloJni and no matter what I do, the compiler can't find any of the standard header files. jni.h, string.h, ect.

I have no experience with Android; I'm just trying to get to the image processing algorithms in OpenARToolkit.

If you have any ideas, I'd be very grateful.

EDIT: This is the output of ndk-build V=1

```
:~/workspace/HelloJni$ ndk-build V=1
Android NDK: WARNING: APP_PLATFORM android-19 is larger than android:minSdkVersion 3 in ./AndroidManifest.xml    
rm -f ./libs/arm64-v8a/lib*.so ./libs/armeabi/lib*.so ./libs/armeabi-v7a/lib*.so ./libs/armeabi-v7a-hard/lib*.so ./libs/mips/lib*.so ./libs/mips64/lib*.so ./libs/x86/lib*.so ./libs/x86_64/lib*.so
rm -f ./libs/arm64-v8a/gdbserver ./libs/armeabi/gdbserver ./libs/armeabi-v7a/gdbserver ./libs/armeabi-v7a-hard/gdbserver ./libs/mips/gdbserver ./libs/mips64/gdbserver ./libs/x86/gdbserver ./libs/x86_64/gdbserver
rm -f ./libs/arm64-v8a/gdb.setup ./libs/armeabi/gdb.setup ./libs/armeabi-v7a/gdb.setup ./libs/armeabi-v7a-hard/gdb.setup ./libs/mips/gdb.setup ./libs/mips64/gdb.setup ./libs/x86/gdb.setup ./libs/x86_64/gdb.setup
[arm64-v8a] Gdbserver      : [aarch64-linux-android-4.9] libs/arm64-v8a/gdbserver
install -p /home/seth/android-ndk-r10e/prebuilt/android-arm64/gdbserver/gdbserver ./libs/arm64-v8a/gdbserver
[arm64-v8a] Gdbsetup       : libs/arm64-v8a/gdb.setup
echo "set solib-search-path ./obj/local/arm64-v8a" > ./libs/arm64-v8a/gdb.setup
echo "source /home/seth/android-ndk-r10e/prebuilt/common/gdb/common.setup" >> ./libs/arm64-v8a/gdb.setup
echo "directory /home/seth/android-ndk-r10e/platforms/android-21/arch-arm64/usr/include jni /home/seth/android-ndk-r10e/sources/cxx-stl/system" >> ./libs/arm64-v8a/gdb.setup
[x86_64] Gdbserver      : [x86_64-4.9] libs/x86_64/gdbserver
install -p /home/seth/android-ndk-r10e/prebuilt/android-x86_64/gdbserver/gdbserver ./libs/x86_64/gdbserver
[x86_64] Gdbsetup       : libs/x86_64/gdb.setup
echo "set solib-search-path ./obj/local/x86_64" > ./libs/x86_64/gdb.setup
echo "source /home/seth/android-ndk-r10e/prebuilt/common/gdb/common.setup" >> ./libs/x86_64/gdb.setup
echo "directory /home/seth/android-ndk-r10e/platforms/android-21/arch-x86_64/usr/include jni /home/seth/android-ndk-r10e/sources/cxx-stl/system" >> ./libs/x86_64/gdb.setup
[mips64] Gdbserver      : [mips64el-linux-android-4.9] libs/mips64/gdbserver
install -p /home/seth/android-ndk-r10e/prebuilt/android-mips64/gdbserver/gdbserver ./libs/mips64/gdbserver
[mips64] Gdbsetup       : libs/mips64/gdb.setup
echo "set solib-search-path ./obj/local/mips64" > ./libs/mips64/gdb.setup
echo "source /home/seth/android-ndk-r10e/prebuilt/common/gdb/common.setup" >> ./libs/mips64/gdb.setup
echo "directory /home/seth/android-ndk-r10e/platforms/android-21/arch-mips64/usr/include jni /home/seth/android-ndk-r10e/sources/cxx-stl/system" >> ./libs/mips64/gdb.setup
[armeabi-v7a] Gdbserver      : [arm-linux-androideabi-4.8] libs/armeabi-v7a/gdbserver
install -p /home/seth/android-ndk-r10e/prebuilt/android-arm/gdbserver/gdbserver ./libs/armeabi-v7a/gdbserver
[armeabi-v7a] Gdbsetup       : libs/armeabi-v7a/gdb.setup
echo "set solib-search-path ./obj/local/armeabi-v7a" > ./libs/armeabi-v7a/gdb.setup
echo "source /home/seth/android-ndk-r10e/prebuilt/common/gdb/common.setup" >> ./libs/armeabi-v7a/gdb.setup
echo "directory /home/seth/android-ndk-r10e/platforms/android-19/arch-arm/usr/include jni /home/seth/android-ndk-r10e/sources/cxx-stl/system" >> ./libs/armeabi-v7a/gdb.setup
[armeabi] Gdbserver      : [arm-linux-androideabi-4.8] libs/armeabi/gdbserver
install -p /home/seth/android-ndk-r10e/prebuilt/android-arm/gdbserver/gdbserver ./libs/armeabi/gdbserver
[armeabi] Gdbsetup       : libs/armeabi/gdb.setup
echo "set solib-search-path ./obj/local/armeabi" > ./libs/armeabi/gdb.setup
echo "source /home/seth/android-ndk-r10e/prebuilt/common/gdb/common.setup" >> ./libs/armeabi/gdb.setup
echo "directory /home/seth/android-ndk-r10e/platforms/android-19/arch-arm/usr/include jni /home/seth/android-ndk-r10e/sources/cxx-stl/system" >> ./libs/armeabi/gdb.setup
[x86] Gdbserver      : [x86-4.8] libs/x86/gdbserver
install -p /home/seth/android-ndk-r10e/prebuilt/android-x86/gdbserver/gdbserver ./libs/x86/gdbserver
[x86] Gdbsetup       : libs/x86/gdb.setup
echo "set solib-search-path ./obj/local/x86" > ./libs/x86/gdb.setup
echo "source /home/seth/android-ndk-r10e/prebuilt/common/gdb/common.setup" >> ./libs/x86/gdb.setup
echo "directory /home/seth/android-ndk-r10e/platforms/android-19/arch-x86/usr/include jni /home/seth/android-ndk-r10e/sources/cxx-stl/system" >> ./libs/x86/gdb.setup
[mips] Gdbserver      : [mipsel-linux-android-4.8] libs/mips/gdbserver
install -p /home/seth/android-ndk-r10e/prebuilt/android-mips/gdbserver/gdbserver ./libs/mips/gdbserver
[mips] Gdbsetup       : libs/mips/gdb.setup
echo "set solib-search-path ./obj/local/mips" > ./libs/mips/gdb.setup
echo "source /home/seth/android-ndk-r10e/prebuilt/common/gdb/common.setup" >> ./libs/mips/gdb.setup
echo "directory /home/seth/android-ndk-r10e/platforms/android-19/arch-mips/usr/include jni /home/seth/android-ndk-r10e/sources/cxx-stl/system" >> ./libs/mips/gdb.setup
[arm64-v8a] Compile        : hello-jni <= hello-jni.c
/home/seth/android-ndk-r10e/toolchains/aarch64-linux-android-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/aarch64-linux-android-gcc -MMD -MP -MF ./obj/local/arm64-v8a/objs-debug/hello-jni/hello-jni.o.d -fpic -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector-strong -no-canonical-prefixes -O2 -g -DNDEBUG -fomit-frame-pointer -fstrict-aliasing -funswitch-loops -finline-limit=300 -O0 -UNDEBUG -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-strict-aliasing -Ijni -DANDROID  -Wa,--noexecstack -Wformat -Werror=format-security    -I/home/seth/android-ndk-r10e/platforms/android-21/arch-arm64/usr/include -c  jni/hello-jni.c -o ./obj/local/arm64-v8a/objs-debug/hello-jni/hello-jni.o 
jni/hello-jni.c:17:20: fatal error: string.h: No such file or directory
 #include <string.h>
                    ^
compilation terminated.
make: *** [obj/local/arm64-v8a/objs-debug/hello-jni/hello-jni.o] Error 1
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. You want to switch from Eclipse to what? You're trying to r̶u̶n̶  build the sample NDK app HelloJni — what exactly did you try? What happens when you type `ndk-build -C <path-to-HelloJni-project>` and hit **`Enter`**?

Comment: I'm not switching to eclipse from anything, I was just explaining why I was using that  rather than Android Studio. 

I get the same error when I run ndk-build from the command line. 


`jni/hello-jni.c:17:20: fatal error: string.h: No such file or directory
 #include <string.h>`

Comment: Let's try to get more info from **ndk-build**: run `ndk-build V=1` and post the output.

Comment: Thanks @Alex Cohn! I've updated the main question with the output of that command.

Comment: *a)* you probably want to set **APP_PLATFORM=3** when you run **ndk-build**. Using 19 will generate a library that may fail to load on lower platforms.

Comment: *b)* may there be **CFLAGS** environment variable defined? may the environment variable redefine **--sysroot**?

Comment: I only have API21 installed in order to save space. I'm not doing proper app development so I'm only targeting the device I'm using. 

CFLAGS is not defined. Should I do this?

Comment: You only have API21 installed - do you speak about Android SDK or you deleted parts of NDK? Another question: do you really intend to build arm64 binary?

Comment: I have successfully built SDK example apps, and run them on my device and the emulator. You are correct, I don't need the arm64 binary, I missed that one.

Comment: so, if you try `ndk-build APP_ABI=armeabi V=1 APP_PLATFORM=android-3`, does it find **string.h**?